# Sequence bounded for all but finitely many terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $c\leq x_n\leq d$ for all but for finitely many $n$'s. Show that $\limsup x_n, \liminf x_n\in [c,d]$

I know this is true if the sequence is bounded for all $n$. But how can I prove this if there is a finite amount of $n$'s that don't hold the first inequality?

Comment: What is your definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$?

Comment: If the limit of a subsequence would be smaller than $c$ , you can show that infinite many entries of this subsequence must be smaller than $c$. Analogue for $d$.